# is it possible to cross-compile from x86(x64) windows to x86(x64) linux?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compiling

I have been wonder about why x86(windows) to arm(linux) cross compile is possible but x86(windows) to x86(linux) cross compile is impossible or difficult only can use cygwin

As below link there is some cross-compiler for windows to arm from personal pc(x86), but there is no cross-compiler x86 to x86.
http://gnutoolchains.com/beaglebone/

why window(x86) to Debian(ARM) is available without cygwin , but window to Debian(x86) is difficult or must use cygwin?

Is this issue caused by POSIX size problem? The library size of Debian in ARM is little bit smaller than x86 ones?

I confuse.... 
I want to anyone clear to me.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: I don't think there are any difficulties, just lack of larger interest to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and then [Debian](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/debian/9msvkqc78pk6?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) as an Windows-App
directly under my Windows10 Home Edition.

Now I can open a Linux command prompt in every directory I want.

Installed g++ with apt-get (changed to root with "sudo su").

Using Mingw64 command prompt from the Git-Bash I can even use the same shell script
to compile console apps as Linux and Windows executables!